# PL/SQL coalesce on variable value

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, coalesce

I'm working on a stored procedure that selects some data from several tables. Some of the tables aren't quite ready for data to be pulled from them so I thought that I could use coalesce and pass in some parameters to the stored procedure on where to get the data from and essentially use null until the data is ready.

```
PROCEDURE SP (frst_name VARCHAR2 default null)
    AS
    BEGIN
SELECT 
    coalesce(frst_name, oldTable.frst_name)
FROM
    oldTable left join newTable on oldTable.Id = newTable.Id    
END SP;
```

Here is a simplified version of the stored procedure.  Is there any way to get this to work?

When I try and compile the stored proc I get Error(37,4): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored.

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention I'm using aliases in the join leading me to think that the issue might actually be with the second coalesce parameter and not the variable that I'm passing in.  I noticed a warning on the 2 aliases saying 'new' is disconnected from the rest of the join graph

```
PROCEDURE SP (frst_name VARCHAR2 default null)
    AS
    BEGIN
SELECT 
    coalesce(frst_name, oldTable.frst_name)
FROM
    oldTable old left join newTable new on oldTable.Id = newTable.Id    
END SP;
```

I've confirmed this by switching the the frst_name variable with null and still getting the same error do you guys have any idea what is going on?

**SOLVED**

Thanks guys but it was a stupid mistake on my part I was using a different database user for stored procedures and I didn't set the synonym or grant access to the user -_- lesson learned!

Comment: That's the whole error stack? You aren't selecting *into* anything, but then you don't have a local variable to select into in the example. The arguments to your `coalesce` may also be the wrong way round, which wouldn't error but might not get the result you want. You also have a scope/precedence problem if your variable and column names are the same. It isn't clear what you're really doing though. Sometimes you can simplify your code so much you hide the issue, and the intent.

Answer (score 0):

u r not using into, and this is not allowed in PL SQL selects .... also u may better use NVL or decode for such simple test .... coalesce is mainly for seledcting first non-null value,

any ways .. here's the correct syntax :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE sp(frst_name VARCHAR2 default null)
AS
v number;
BEGIN
SELECT 
coalesce(oldTable.frst_name,frst_name)
into v
FROM
oldTable left join newTable 
on oldTable.ID = newTable.ID;
END sp;
```

also use SQL developer for more declarative error messages, it's free !

Comment: That isn't correct; you've declared `v` as a number instead of a string, and there's still a naming resolution problem for the unqualified `frst_name`. It also isn't really clear from the question that swapping the coalesce terms is right. (And what's wrong with the standard coalesce? And please don't use txt spk in your posts)

Comment: I am using coalesce because if the column in the new table is null i'd still like to pull data from the old table which I know isn't null. This is a simplified version of the actual stored proc but when I run the select alone by itself it runs fine exactly how I want it. I am also using SQL Developer and that's All I see in the compiler log is there somewhere else I should be looking?